# Margin not working in TextField using MUI makeStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I am trying to add margin to my `TextField` component by making an object of `makestyles` using MUI v5.
The background color is reflecting in the component but not margin and padding. Here is my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Typography } from '@mui/material'
import { Button } from '@mui/material'
import { ButtonGroup } from '@mui/material'
import { Container } from '@mui/material'
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
```

Here I have used makeStyles

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  field: {
    // paddingTop: '20px',
    padding: '100px',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    marginBottom: '100px',
    // margin: 100
    // display: 'block'
  },
});

export default function Create() {
  const classes = useStyles()
return (
    <Container>


      <Typography
        variant="h6"
        component="h2"
        gutterBottom
        color="textSecondary"
      >
        Create a New Note
      </Typography>

      <form noValidate autoComplete="off" >
        <TextField
          
          className={classes.field}
          label="Note Title"
          variant="outlined"
          color="secondary"
          fullWidth
          required
          error={titleError}
        >
        </TextField>
        <Button
          type="submit"
          color="secondary"

          variant="outlined"
          onClick={() => console.log("you clicked me")}

          endIcon={<KeyboardArrowRightOutlinedIcon />}

        >Submit </Button>
      </form>

  </Container>
  )
}
```

All of this is in a single file

Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjXfG.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TextField` is just a wrapper component of the `Input` inside it, to target the input for styling, you can use `InputProps`:

```
<TextField
  InputProps={{
    className: classes.field
  }}
```

**EDIT**: The `margin` doesn't work in your `TextField` because of the CSS specificity. Your style is overrode by the other one from emotion, to fix it, double the className using this technique:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  field: {
    // append the same classname to increase the specificity
    // output has something like: .makeStyles-field-5.makeStyles-field-5
    "&&": {
      marginBottom: "100px"
    }
  }
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: No, I am trying to add a margin to the ```TextField``` itself, and not to the input.

Comment: @RoninS28 See my updated answer.

Comment: Brilliant! It worked right away. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for that syntax for doubling the class name. Where is that documented?